# How to attach sql database to a javascript graph

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, database-connection

I'm creating a website using asp mvc5 and i need to show some data on a view using a graph.
i have implemented a graph using javascript.

```
<head>
    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/chart.script.js"></script>
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/finalstylesheet.css">*@

</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Daily Booking</div>
            @*<div class="panel-body">*@
                @*<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-8" style="background-color:#4876FF;">Show</div>
                <div class="col-lg-2"></div>*@
                <br><br>
                <div class='wrapper'>
                    <canvas height='150' id='canvas' width='170'></canvas>
                </div>
            @*</div>*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myData = {
            labels: ["9:00", "12:00", "15:00", "18:00"],
            datasets: [


              {
                  fillColor: "rgba(072,118,225,.5)",
                  strokeColor: "rgba(001,001,190,1)",
                  pointColor: "rgba(001,001,190,1)",
                  pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                  data: [40, 25, 90, 40]
              }
            ]
        }

        new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(myData)
    </script>
</body>
```

i have a database.

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=ACER-PC\CAD;Initial Catalog=IT;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I want to get values from customer_age table and show that in graph. How am i supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the structure of your `customer_age` table, this should help you along your way:

Use an AJAX call to fetch the data from an MVC controller action (or, more efficiently, a Web API method). Then, when the data returns, build your chart. It looks like your chart needs two data arrays: one for the labels and the other for the values. Instead of providing two separate AJAX endpoints to return the two series we'll return an array of objects, each of which has two properties: a label and a corresponding value.

E.g.:

```
$.ajax ({
  url: 'Url.Action("YourAction","YourController")',
  //data: {} //include this if you need to pass parameters to your query
  type: 'get',
  success: function(result) {
    if (!result.success)
      alert(result.message);
    else {
      var myData = {
        labels: result.data.map(function(i){return i.label;}),
        datasets: [


          {
              fillColor: "rgba(072,118,225,.5)",
              strokeColor: "rgba(001,001,190,1)",
              pointColor: "rgba(001,001,190,1)",
              pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
              data: result.data.map(function(i){return i.value;})
          }
        ]
      }

      new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Line(myData)

    }
  }
});
```

The controller action could look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetChartData() {
  try {
    //get data from repository
    var data = CustomerRepository.GetChartData();
    //convert to format expected by Javascript - should be done in repository method
    return Json(new { success=true, 
        data = (from d in data select new {label = d.Label, value=d.Value}).ToArray()
      }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     return Json(new {success=false, message=e.Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```